# Firefox <img> placement issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

The following url:
http://richtechgala.com/

The logo in the header should be centered, and if you are on Chrome or Safari, you will see this. However, when I go on Firefox, the image is forced outside of the header, completely off the current viewport. I'm not using any special rules that would require vendor prefixes...whats going on here?

This is how the logo should look, currently on Chrome:
[image: The way the logo should look, this is on Chrome]

This is what it looks like on Firefox (I used the 3d model for a better visualization):
[image]

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing (or post only an image) - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks! 
Preview:

Comment: Also you may want to run your code through an HTML validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is causing this, but you can fix like this:

```
header {
   text-align: center
}
header img {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that your list items inside of the first nav are floating. You could apply a clearfix for it (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) but I think it is better to use inline block as I have below

Also you should copy/paste the code for a simplified version of the header area on the question instead of posting a link

```
.universal li {
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Since they are floating, it takes them out of the normal document flow and it needs to be cleared

You can set the list items to `display: inline-block` instead but this will require you to kill the space between each item

like so

```
<nav class="universal container-fluid">
    <ul>
        <li>
            ...                 
        </li><li>
            ...
        </li>....
    </ul>
</nav>
```

you could also do

```
<nav class="universal container-fluid">
    <ul>
        <li>
            ...                 
        </li><!--
        --><li>
            ...
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.universal li {
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Also due to

```
.universal ul {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

there is a horizontal scrollbar, delete that rule as there is no need for it

As a closing note, I would suggest you copy and paste the code for your header area into the question (edit it) and copy the corresponding css as well so it will be more useful for future users. You can also setup a http://jsfiddle.net it makes debugging much easier

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, on the problem and the posting itself.

Comment: @la1ch3 I highly recommend you taking a close look at the issue and the solution as this won't be the last time you run into this. Also that scrollbar issue I mentioned is still there